# Restore local branch from corrupt header

Tags: git, branch, commit

Yesterday I made a first commit to a branch called `award_end_scenario`. I forgot to push it into the repo, and decided to updated my Git Client (Git Kraken). I had a power outage while it was updating, getting my local clone messed up.

The following file exists: `\.git\refs\heads\award_end_scenario` but it is corrupted: it doesn't have inside it any head reference.

So, my question is: what could I do to restore all my work? Can I restore my local branch somehow?

When I open git it is currently in that branch, but it's corrupt state is visible once I run `git log` and `git branch -a`, which states that the current branch is broken, and that HEAD is not a valid reference, respectively.

Thank you!

Comment: does `git reflog` provide any useful info?

Comment: fatal: your current branch appears to be broken

Comment: Since the corrupt branch is the one current in "use", I was able to restore some files that I remember I changed, since it is git who is messed up and not the files. However, it would be nice to resolve this situation without relying on my memory of which files I've changed...

Comment: Might have to take a look at the object database to see what's there to rescue... but I'm not that knowledgeable on it.

Comment: `git diff master` correctly shows the files that have been changed. Should I commit these changes to a new branch? I'm not sure if it recognizes these changes as something committed or not.

Comment: If you want to commit "following" master, you could then `git reset --soft master; git commit -m "Rescuing files.... hope this commit works"`. If that works, you can place a branch there (or move master to it if you feel like it).

Comment: Backup everything, just in case :-)

Comment: Will that commit into master, or into a new branch? The latter is the desired.

Comment: That will take your branch pointer with you. If you are working on a branch, it will take the branch. If you are working on detached head, no branch will be moved and you will remain on **detached HEAD state**.

Comment: Trying the soft reset: `$ git reset --soft master;
error: update_ref failed for ref 'HEAD': cannot lock ref 'HEAD': unable to resolve reference HEAD: Invalid argument`

Comment: It looks so bad! :-) Can you fetch using this repo as a remote?

Comment: Sorry, could you be more explicit? I'm not very comfortable with using git in the command line :P Also, if I just `checkout new_branch` would that branch be a "child" of this corrupt branch? Or would it be independent from it?

Comment: in git branches are just pointers to revisions that can be moved around at will, so branches are not parents or children. Revisions on the other hand do point to their parents. Hope that helps a little bit with your question about parents....anyway... what I'm saying is: this repo looks messed up (as if you didn't know). Perhaps you could set up a repo on the side (locally), set up the broken repo as a remote of the new repo and see what comes out of fetching from the original one.

Answer (score 0):

After trying `git checkout master` the changes were still there, uncommitted. I then ran:

```
git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all
git gc --prune=now
```

And was able to create a new branch and commit the changes to the new branch. All working fine now!